# JavaScript calculations

Tags: javascript

Here is the updated version of my code. I can see the values for p // pay rate and m // markup % only in the console of the browser they aren't showing up in the assigned fields of the form loandata.

```
var b, p, m, pmp, pm, pb, fp, misc, wc, tax, sui, o, fp, misc, t;
function calculate1(){
    wc = document.set.wc.value; // workers comp %
    tax = document.set.tax.value; // taxes %
    sui = document.set.sui.value; // sui %
    o = document.set.o.value; // other expenses %
    fp =document.set.fp.value; // fund and processing %
    misc = document.set.misc.value; // Misc expenses %
    pb = (wc+tax+sui+o)/100*b; // variable used to calculate profit margin
    document.set.pb.value = pb;
    t = document.set.t.value; // target profit margin %
}
function calculate() {
    b = document.loandata.b.value; //bill rate
    b = (b=="")?(((m*p)/ 100) + p):b; 
    p = document.loandata.p.value; //pay rate 
    m = document.loandata.m.value; // markup % 
    m = (m=="")?((b-p)/p* 100):m;
    pm = (b-((pb*p)/100+(b*fp)/100+(b*misc)/100+p)); // profit margin calculation
    pm = Math.round(pm).toFixed(2);
    document.loandata.pm.value = pm;
    pmp = pm/b*100;  // profit margin % calc 
    pmp = Math.round(pmp).toFixed(2); // profit margin %
    document.loandata.pmp.value = pmp;
}
```

Comment: -1 for all of those evil and totally pointless `eval`s.

Comment: +1, @Kolink, for pointing out the abuse of `eval`s. Anyway, what on earth? All these abbreviated variables names, ambiguous function names, lack of comments, a serious lack of semi-colons, functions that don't accept arguments and instead get them themselves, missing var keywords, unnecessary variable assignments, etc. WTF? You haven't even indicated what the variables mean because you refer to them as their ambiguous names.

Comment: To be clear, Kolink is saying that the `eval`s are unnecessary because you can say `wc = document.set.wc.value` and so forth for all the other calculations. @Tyler Crompton - I agree with everything you said _except_ about the lack of semi-colons: semi-colons are mostly optional in JS. Personally I prefer to use them all the time, but the code as shown is completely valid without them. (Though I guess I do still kind of agree given that the code used them in a couple of places and I figure it should be consistent: either use 'em _only_ when necessary or _all the time_...)

Comment: @user1078259 See here for a good explanation about why `eval` is not good: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#core.eval The rest of that page/site is also excellent, and might help you improve your Javascript skills. In particular, I would highlight that you should try to avoid omitting semi-colons at the ends of lines, they are a necessary part of the language that the compiler will try and insert if you don't, and it often does a bad job of guessing where they should go.

Comment: @GregL - Using semi-colons all the time is my preference, but if you leave 'em out the compiler doesn't "guess" where they should go, it follows a clearly defined (and relatively easy to use) set of rules about exactly when and when not to insert them for you.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm sure you are right, the word "guess" was technically incorrect, but I have seen enough examples where it has either determined a semi-colon unnecessary where it was actually necessary, or conversely that one is necessary in a place that will break the code. Given this, if you try to always use semi-colons (along with always using [1TBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS)), then you help minimise the risk of the compiler breaking your code for you.

Comment: To change something in my last comment: "missing var keywords" to "global variables". That's a no-no. @GregL, The compiler basically keeps running through the code ignoring a lack of semi-colons. However, once it finds an "error" it goes back and inserts a semi-colon at the end of the previous line to see if that fixes it and so on. That's the basic idea. It is bad practice to leave out semi-colons. You basically leaving it up to the compiler to determine what you want whereas you could easily just tell it what you want with one measily character here and there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 m = (m==undefined)?(formula for m):m;
 p = (p==undefined)?(formula for p):p;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are explicitly checking if `m==undefined`, instead of just `m ? (formula for m) : m`?

Comment: `m ?` tests if `m` is *falsy* in javascript - not necessarily *equal to* `undefined`. See http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript - `m` could be zero.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Good point. Do you know if there is a practical difference between `(typeof m === 'undefined')` and `m == undefined`?

Comment: @GregL, `m` could somehow get set to `false` or `0` or an empty string or `null` or `NaN` or an empty array or an empty object. Not 100% if the last two evaluate to false but it would make sense (even though JS arithmetic doesn't make sense).

Comment: Good point back at you. `m == undefined` will actually be `true` if `m` is `null` (I think...). `typeof` and strict equals is probably the most absolutely safe way.

Comment: It amazes me how much debate and confusion the darn type coercion behaviour of JS can cause. But it is through sites and conversations like this that we can all be a little less confused.

Comment: @ChrisNash, when you say formula for m you mean how to get to the value m like m = (m==undefined)?((b - p) / p * 100):m; or I just leave the text? Also do I need to to used the  document.loandata.m.value = m to set the variable or just use your code? Thanks , Alek js noob.

Comment: Yes, that's right, insert your specific formula. And I'd say copy all your variables (`b`, `p`, `m`) from the document *before* you start, simply to save typing. You'll have to find what `m` is once you copy it from `document.loandata.m.value` or whatever when that field is not filled out. Probably an empty string, in which case test for that rather than `undefined`.

Comment: I did some reading on JS and understood what your equation meant. I did inspect the values in the fields and the seem to be empty strings.What I did noticed is that even when  the field is an empty string it doesn't execute the calculation. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'd suggest you go ahead and update your question (and your question title) with the latest code and we can help you out from there.

Comment: I got the calculation to work but they can only be seen in the console of the browser. For some reason the calculations ((m*p)/ 100) + p) it gives me some bad math. Weird!